# %dopar% doesn't work after loading a dataset that comes from a different session

Tags: r, doparallel

I'm using R on a cluster node with doParallel and foreach packages (OpenMP).

I've ran a first script that gave me two objects as results and saved them as RData.

On a separate script i load the RData that contains the two objects to be further treated but i get a "task 1, cannot open the connection" when i use a foreach loop in parallel. I suspected the loaded RData might be at fault.

I decided to try this simple working example on my desktop computer:

1/ I first run this simple code:

```
library("doParallel")
library("foreach")
registerDoParallel(cores=3)

x<-matrix(rnorm(2000),nrow=10,ncol=200)
squarex<-foreach(i=1:10)%dopar%{x[,i]^2}
```

Everything works

2/then i load the RData i saved previously on the cluster

```
load("xxx.RData")
```

The two objects are there.

3/if i try to run again 1, which is completely unrelated to 2, then i get the error:

Error in mcfork() : 
  unable to fork, possible reason: Cannot allocate memory

Actually everything that uses the parallel package doesn't work anymore. Trying to register cores doesn't work and sometimes even hangs.

Obviously something must have been imported from the cluster environnement into the RData that causes the problem. However i don't know why and the problem still exists if i do the same steps directly on the cluster.

INFO:

ls() before loading dataset:

```
ls()
[1] "squarex" "x"
```

ls() after loading dataset:
    ls()

```
[1] "squarex"                      "trandom_list_data_Ana_all"         "trandom_list_data_Anatem_all"
[4] "x"
```

trandom_list* are the two objects loaded and each are 8.7Gb (the cluster node has 47Gb and my computer 32Gb of RAM)

dput(xxx.RData) gives a 4,9Gb text file that starts with 
    list(structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 5.2

and ends strangely with

```
2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 31.5, 11.9, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 2.5, 10.2
```

that is without a ")".. maybe de dput wasn't done completely as the RAM with full when the process was done (but the swap was still ok).

Comment: Interesting problem but would be easier to work on if you supply (via `dput` ) reproducible samples of your  `xxx.Rdata` objects.  It's possible you've loaded a large object, for example.  Also please post the result of `ls`  before and after loading your dataset.

Comment: Probably those large items have used up all the memory available to the `R` application itself, hence no space left to call functions.   A little searching on StackOverflow should get you some answers on how to increase the memory allocation to `R`

Comment: How can it be? I've ran rsessions with objects up to 20+Gb with up to 30Gb of RAM used by the rsession and still could call the functions. Actually executing the scripts that give the two objects (trandom*) and doing subsequent operations on them works. It is only when using load that problem arises.

Comment: OK, then my guess was wrong :-( .